# Как в objective-c сделать кнопку временно неактивной, а потом вновь активной?

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone, apple

Я понимаю что это азы,
но тем не менее помогите советом - 
мне нужно сделать кнопку неактивной (видимой но неактивной),
а затем снова ее активировать

Благодарю сердечно )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У всех наследников [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) есть свойство [`enabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled)

Чтоб сделать кнопку неактивной просто установите это свойство в `NO`

```
button.enabled = NO;
```

и наоборот

```
button.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: спасибо все заработало )

Comment: Не за что, не ленитесь читать документацию ;)